# disable subdirectory php/access with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I'm making a site in which people will be able to upload files to a specific subdirectory. Just in case someone were able to bypass the filters for uploading potentially malicious (presumably php) files, I wondering if it is possible to make the malicious code inaccessible. I am looking at 2 different methods.

The first is to see if there was a way with to make it so you cannot access any files in the subdirectory by typing the files url into the browser (www.example.com/images/blahblah.jpg), but have the files still appear properly when linked to by `<img src=images/blahblah.jpg />`

The second way to accomplish this could be to disable php in the subdirectory with the .htaccess file.  I've tried `php_admin_flag engine off`,

`php_flag engine off`,

`RemoveHandler .php
RemoveType .php
php_flag engine off
Options -ExecCGI`

but each try either does nothing, or disables everything in the directory. Is there a reason these are not working? What is the best way to disable php or secure a directory with .htaccess?

Comment: why don't you just secure your upload system so it wont allow files not in a whitelist to be uploaded? What if they upload .pl or .py? Also you can't restrict access to direct URL while still allowing that URL to be accessed by SRC, server has no easy way of knowing which is which.

Comment: ive secured my uploads system by filtering out files by file extension and type, but being that im relatively new to securing websites im trying to be as cautious as possible. are there other ways to secure the upload system?

Comment: Post the upload code and PHP experts on SO will have a chance to peer-review it. =o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the metadata about the uploaded files in a Db and store the content rather in a custom extension text file. For example everything uploaded could be stored as 1.ext or file.my or no extension at all. And when the file is requested  you will just read and dump its content. Adding to this will be to rename all files uploaded.

You can also keep the original files out of the document root( and its subdirectory ) and with the help of .htaccess have all request forwarded to a single file lets call entrance.php Then that php file will simply read the file and dump its content or issue a 404 if not found or not the type allowed.

Hope it helps.